# Is there anyway to make this an interactive background?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to make an interactive background where wherever the mouse hovers or goes to, the lines in this background flows or follows the mouse in that certain direction. Is there anyway I could do this by using HTML/CSS/JavaScript? Here is the code. CSS is on the top, JS on the bottom.

**//CSS**

```
canvas {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

**//JS**

```
// Init Context
let c = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d')
let postctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')
let canvas = c.canvas
let vertices = []

// Effect Properties
let vertexCount = 7000
let vertexSize = 2
let oceanWidth = 204
let oceanHeight = -80
let gridSize = 32;
let waveSize = 16;
let perspective = 500;

// Common variables
let depth = (vertexCount / oceanWidth * gridSize)
let frame = 0
let { sin, cos, tan, PI } = Math

// Render loop
let loop = () => {
    let rad = sin(frame / 100) * PI / 20
  let rad2 = sin(frame / 50) * PI / 10
    frame++
    if (postctx.canvas.width !== postctx.canvas.offsetWidth || postctx.canvas.height !== postctx.canvas.offsetHeight) { 
    postctx.canvas.width = canvas.width = postctx.canvas.offsetWidth
    postctx.canvas.height = canvas.height = postctx.canvas.offsetHeight
  }


    c.fillStyle = `hsl(200deg, 100%, 2%)`
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  c.save()
  c.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)

  c.beginPath()
  vertices.forEach((vertex, i) => {
    let ni = i + oceanWidth
    let x = vertex[0] - frame % (gridSize * 2)
    let z = vertex[2] - frame * 2 % gridSize + (i % 2 === 0 ? gridSize / 2 : 0)
    let wave = (cos(frame / 45 + x / 50) - sin(frame / 20 + z / 50) + sin(frame / 30 + z*x / 10000))
    let y = vertex[1] + wave * waveSize
    let a = Math.max(0, 1 - (Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + z ** 2)) / depth)
    let tx, ty, tz

    y -= oceanHeight

    // Transformation variables
    tx = x
    ty = y
    tz = z

    // Rotation Y
    tx = x * cos(rad) + z * sin(rad)
    tz = -x * sin(rad) + z * cos(rad)

    x = tx
    y = ty
    z = tz

    // Rotation Z
    tx = x * cos(rad) - y * sin(rad)
    ty = x * sin(rad) + y * cos(rad) 

    x = tx;
    y = ty;
    z = tz;

    // Rotation X

    ty = y * cos(rad2) - z * sin(rad2)
    tz = y * sin(rad2) + z * cos(rad2)

    x = tx;
    y = ty;
    z = tz;

    x /= z / perspective
    y /= z / perspective



    if (a < 0.01) return
    if (z < 0) return


    c.globalAlpha = a
    c.fillStyle = `hsl(${180 + wave * 20}deg, 100%, 50%)`
    c.fillRect(x - a * vertexSize / 2, y - a * vertexSize / 2, a * vertexSize, a * vertexSize)
    c.globalAlpha = 1
  })
  c.restore()

  // Post-processing
  postctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)

  postctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen"
  postctx.filter = 'blur(16px)'
  postctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)
  postctx.filter = 'blur(0)'
  postctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"

  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

// Generating dots
for (let i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
    let x = i % oceanWidth
  let y = 0
  let z = i / oceanWidth >> 0
    let offset = oceanWidth / 2
    vertices.push([(-offset + x) * gridSize, y * gridSize, z * gridSize])
}

loop()
```

Comment: Can you please make a jsFiddle with this example?

Comment: Could this help https://codepen.io/niittymaa/pen/OJPRjpx

Comment: Is that your code?

Comment: Yes. That is the code I am using